# Control loss with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, controls

I wrote this Javascript for a website I am creating and I am not sure why the code runs automatically, one of my solutions is to write a function/create a timer so that the code runs at the time I want it to.

here is the js:

```
var introCap = document.getElementById("captionCol");
var imgDiv = document.getElementById("imgCol");
var introDiv = document.getElementById("intro");
var expose = document.getElementById("gotoPage");
var fade = 1;
var l = 15;
var r = 45;

//expose.onclick = move; this is commented out for the time being.

function stop() {
    clearInterval(moveInt);
    clearInterval(fadeInt);
    }

function fadeOut() {
   fade -= 0.07;

   introDiv.style.opacity = fade;
   introDiv.style.filter = "alpha('"+fade+"')";
   if(introDiv.style.opacity<0) {
        stop();
       }
    }
    var fadeInt = setInterval("fadeOut()", 60);

function move() {
    l -= 0.1;
    r +=  0.1;

    introCap.style.left = r+"%";
    imgDiv.style.left = l+"%";

    if (imgDiv.style.left<10) {
    fadeOut();
    }
   }
   var moveInt = setInterval("move()", 70);
```

here is the corresponding html:

```
<div id="intro">

        <div id="imgCol"></div>

        <div id="captionCol">
            <p> Hi, I'm <b>Jenny Spring</b>. <br><br>
            I'm a <span id="emp">SPIN</span> farmer. </p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="#" id="gotoPage">Go To</a></p> <!-- this link will be changed to a button later but is being used as is temporarily.

</div>
```

Is anyone able to tell why the code performs automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically" ?

Comment: When the page is loaded, the script runs and the animation happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` not only sets the interval, but it also calls the function after each interval. So do not use this function until you are ready to call it. Another function, `setTimeout()` is available, which executes the function only once.

For example, you can move interval calls to a function `start()` and use your href to act as a start button

```
function start() {
    var moveInt = setInterval("move()", 70);
    var fadeInt = setInterval("fadeOut()", 60);
}

<p><a href="javascript:start();" id="gotoPage">Go To</a></p>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Thanks J L, that is a pretty good suggestion. I am implementing your idea, and running into other little issues. I think this will work once I get all the kinks out. Cheers!

Comment: It worked, I was tinkering with the code and forgot that I inserted my script tags above the div="intro" elements, so all my variables were coming up as null. Thanks again!